# ACRA isn't working but I set it up correctly

Tags: java, android, acra

I'm in `Android Studio` using ACRA on Android for my application and I am fairly sure that everything is correctly set up:

```
package prospect.firmname.net.prospect;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

import org.acra.*;
import org.acra.annotation.*;
import org.acra.sender.HttpSender;

import static org.acra.ACRA.log;

@ReportsCrashes(
    formUri = "http://prospect.firmname.net/report.php",
    reportType = HttpSender.Type.JSON,
    httpMethod = HttpSender.Method.POST,
    customReportContent = {
            ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE,
            ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME,
            ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION,
            ReportField.PACKAGE_NAME,
            ReportField.REPORT_ID,
            ReportField.BUILD,
            ReportField.STACK_TRACE
    },
    mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST
)
public class ProspectApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        log.e("ACRA BOOTING","OK");
        ACRA.init(this);
    }
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        ACRA.init(this);
    }
  }
```

I added the `log.e("ACRA BOOTING","OK");` and it appears in debugging, and I put in *both* `@overrides` out of desperation, but originally it was as [this page here](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup):

the mainfest looks like this

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:name="ProspectApplication"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">            
           ~~~~
    </application>
```

the gradle file looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "prospect.firmname.net.prospect"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

when I visit the url `http://prospect.firmname.net/report.php` manually (touch the website) it logs the visit, perfectly because I use this code ( I added a error_log to be 100% sure it works), it logs a visit when I do it manually it NEVER logs a visit if the app crashes:

```
report.php 
<?php
    // Outputs all POST parameters to a text file. The file name is the date_time of the report reception
    error_log("_REQUEST called " . print_r($_REQUEST,true),0);
    $fileName = 'acra/'.date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').'.txt';
    $file = fopen($fileName,'w') or die('Could not create report file: ' . $fileName);
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $reportLine = $key." = ".$value."\n";
        fwrite($file, $reportLine) or die ('Could not write to report file ' . $reportLine);
    }
    fclose($file);
?>
```

can anyone explin why nothing happens?

Comment: In the AndroidManifest.xml, in the name of the custom application class you should add a dot before the class name like this `android:name=".ProspectApplication"` and i'm confident you added the internet permission

Comment: thanks : I changed it to a `.` and it's not helped, (that was why the `log.e` is in there, and that ran the whole time) and yes I have the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
`

Comment: But are you calling `log.e("ACRA BOOTING","OK");` before the `ACRA.init(this)` line?? you can't send errors prior to initializing the library...

Comment: `log.e("ACRA BOOTING","OK")` isn't a error it's just writing to the pipe, for use in the debugger - I use `throw new RuntimeException("ACRA is alive!");` to trigger ACRA in ActivityMain

Comment: Call `ACRA.DEV_LOGGING = true` before init and filter your log for any messages with the `ACRA` tag.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need a `.` before the name: `android:name=".ProspectApplication"`.

Secondly, you have this line:

```
 mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST
```

But you have no text to show in the toast. You need to add resToastId:

```
resToastText=R.string.errorMessage
```

or nothing is shown in the Toast

Comment: thanks, but I've already commented about the "." what has TOAST (or has not) got to do with any of this? Ignore that line if you like. It'll not make it work

Comment: the toast is a bug I saw in the code he had, he shows a toast without content.